# Debian 10 Live remove gnu start-up beep

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, gnu

When I select the USB in the boot selection I get a really loud beep sound and I couldn't find how to remove it.

I've tried  looking for the `^G` in `menu.cfg` but at least in my version I couldn't find it.

**· Is that beep from the Debian OS or from my PC?**

**· Can I remove it so that it never plays on any computer?** (since I use the USB in multiple computers)

Comment: If you know that it is a Gnu start-up beep, then you know where it is from. Is this correct? (Sorry I don't see what this word is doing. What is its purpose. Am I missing something?)

Comment: The reason of that is that for what I know is how that screen is called, because it was named like that in the sites I looked on. But in other guides is was said that it came from the BIOS, that's what confuses me.

Comment: so you don't know. Are you asking if it is, as I still am not sure why you are asserting that it is a Gnu start up beep, and then asking where it comes from and what is it. Please don't try to answer the question in the title.  It just ends up in a mess.

Comment: Take into account that `^G` is only one representation of the [bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), your text editor may render it differently. Try removing the `menu title` line altogether, and retyping it (the title text is arbitrary).